# gdb finds debugging information but cannot put breakpoint

Tags: python, c, debugging, memory, gdb

I have a python code that is calling a shared library written in C (and compiled with debugging information with flags: `-g -O0 -Wall -fPIC`). 
I want to step into the c code with `gdb`. I do the following:

- I call the python code from terminal and step internally with a call to `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` within the code.
- I attach the process to `gdb` to the pid of the python process

When I attach with `gdb`, some debugging information about system library are not found (obviously), but the debugging information for my shared library are found. When I try to put a breakpoint into one of the source file of the so, I write `b filename.c:30`, but `gdb` says that it cannot access memory:

```
Cannot access memory at address 0x128a
```

Could the reason be that I have compiled the library with `icc` and I am debugging `gdb`?
In case I would be a bit surprised because I have successfully debugged other programs compiled with intel with `gdb`.

Any thoughts?

---

Edit: 
I have recompiled with gcc and I still have this problem. I was thinking that for putting a breakpoint I would need instead the name of the function within the shared library, that I guess has a prefix, something like `lib.function`. how could I know that prefix?

Edit2:
I am puzzled by the fact that if I write `list <name of function>`, `gdb` will show me the correct source code corresponding to the function

---

Edit:

following directions in one of the answers I have opened gdb and entered the following commands:

```
(gdb)info functions f 
All functions matching regular expression "f":

File ../source/ffile.c:
double f(double, double, double, double, double);

Non-debugging symbols:
0x0000000000000a68 f@plt
(gdb)break f
Cannot access memory at address 0x124a
```

Comment: It would help if you showed the exact error.  If gdb can "list" properly it means it is finding the debuginfo.  The error suggests perhaps the kernel is rejecting the request; or that there is some bug in the debuginfo.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two reasons:

- The library is not mapped yet or
- You hit bug# 54151 , have a look at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=54151

Comment: what does 'the library is not mapped yet' mean? I have updated my question